# I am trying to create 4 buttons in HTML that calls the following functions such as Adding, Subtracting, Multiplying, dividing

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick, calculator

I am new to JavaScript and I'm a bit confused about what I'm doing wrong. For this Assignment I need to create 4 buttons in HTML that calls the following functions such as adding, subtracting, multiplying and dividing. I am suppose to prompt the user to enter two numbers and then it will calculate it.

I figured out how to make one adding button but for some reason I am having trouble creating the other buttons for - * /. I am also not sure why it doesn't keep track of the calculations for the subtraction buttons and etc. I am kind of confused how to create multiple functions and buttons all in one program.

```js
function add() {

  var num1, num2, num3;

  numAdd1 = parseInt(prompt("Enter First Number:"));
  numAdd2 = parseInt(prompt("Enter Second Number:"));
  numAdd3 = numAdd1 + numAdd2



  resultAdd = "Result is " + String(numAdd3)
  //document.write(numAdd3 + "<br>")


  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = resultAdd;

}

function sub() {

  var sub1, sub2, sub3;


  sub1 = parseInt(prompt("Enter First Number:"));
  sub2 = parseInt(prompt("Enter Second Number:"));
  sub3 = sub1 - sub2



  result2 = "result is : " + String(numSub3)
  //document.write(Sub3 + "<br>")


  document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = result2;

}
```

```html
<button onclick="add()">Press to Add</button>
<p id="result">Result:</p>

<button onclick="sub()">Press to Subtract</button>
<p id="result2">Result:</p>

<button onclick="Multiply()">Press to Multiply</button>
<p id="result">Result:</p>

<button onclick="Divide()">Press to Divide</button>
<p id="result2">Result:</p>
```

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Answer (score 0):

You kind of made a typo. At the end of the `result2` variable "assignment"(which means to set the value of the variable), and you used the wrong name for the variable. `numSub3` should be `sub3`.

```
result2 = "result is : " + String(sub3);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I didn't realize that. I corrected it and now it works. I see my teacher has created two assignments. One that says he wants the output the values with returns. Do you know how I would modify this program to output the values with return?

Comment: Actually I don't know but i will try to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome, and good luck with the assignment.  Nice start!

I would recommend using `input` elements for your numeric inputs, as I have shown in this partial example.  Also, be sure to shoot for consistency in your variable naming and general code layout.  The sooner you develop those habits the better.

And challenge yourself to add a few bells and whistles!

```js
function run(operator) {
  const values = getValues();
  const result = calculate(values.left, values.right, operator);
  writeResult(result);
}

function calculate(left, right, operator) {

  if (operator === '+') {
    return left + right;
  }
  if (operator === '-') {
    return left - right;
  }
  /* 
  add rest of operations...
  */
  throw Error('Invalid operator passed in');
}

function getValues() {
  return {
    left: +document.getElementById('left').value,
    right: +document.getElementById('right').value,
  }
}

function writeResult(result) {
  document.getElementById('result').innerText = result;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="left" />
<input type="number" id="right" />
<br/>
<button onclick="run('+')">Add</button>
<button onclick="run('-')">Subtract</button> ...more buttons
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I corrected it and now it works. I see my teacher has created two assignments. One that says he wants the output the values with returns. Do you know how I would modify this program to output the values with return?

Comment: Sure, modified it so you don't have a function have too may responsibilities. Here is a possible way to rewrite it so we have a one function to get our values, one function to perform the operation, and one function to write the values.  And one function to 'run' it all together.